# Algorithm to remove duplicate elements from an array written in pseudocode

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

i am trying to write an algorithm that will remove any duplicate element from an array passed in as paramater. i struggled with making it only with the array as paramater, so i added another parameter which would be the array  size.

i want the algorithm to remove the duplicate elements and returns the array with the non duplicate elements.

here is what i've written

```
Algorithm RemDup(arr[0..n-1],k)

j<--0
m<--0
for i<--0 to i<k do
    for j<--i+1 to j<k do
        if arr[i]=arr[j]then
            for m=j to m<k do
                arr[m] = arr[m+1]
            endfor
            k<-- k-1
            j<-- j-1
        endif
    endfor
endfor
return arr
```

is this a correct method? and is there a way to make this algorithm with only the array passed as a parameter?

Comment: Seems correct, although not very efficient, could be improved quite a lot. There is just one mistake: the length of the array itself doesn't get reduced (only k) if you find duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to remove the array length 'k' from function parameter, you can read the array length inside the function and assign it to 'k'.
Your algorithm is looks good for unsorted array. If it is for sorted array you can remove one loop from your algorithm as shown in below. In below algorithm, I have used same input array to store the final output. So returning final index value 'j' of output array (After removing duplicates).

Refer this link for detailed analysis: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-sorted-array/

```
Algorithm RemDup(arr[0..n-1])

k<--arr.length
j<--0

for i<--0 to i<k do    
  if arr[i]!=arr[i+1]then
  arr[j] = arr[i]
  j<--j+1
  end if
endfor
```

// Store the last element as whether   it is unique or repeated, it hasn't stored previously

```
    arr[j] = arr[n-1];  
return arr,j
```

I hope it helps your question.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a common way of removing duplicates is as follows:

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  .filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i)
);
```

Here, you loop through the array to find the very first match. If it's position is not the same position of the current element, then it must be a duplicate and you ignore it. In pseudocode:

```
Algorithm RemDup(arr[0..n-1],k)

i<--0
m<--0
while i<k do
    skip<--false
    for j<--0 to j<i do
        if arr[i]=arr[j]then
            skip<--true
            break
        endif
    endfor
    if skip do
        for m=i to m<k do
            arr[m] = arr[m+1]
        endfor
        k<--k-1
    else
        i<--i+1
    endif
endfor
return arr
```